# Get a single post ID based on an exact match of 1 or more meta values

Tags: meta-query

I'd like to find the post ID based on an exact match of meta values (could be more than 1). All the examples I have found show find the post ID from 1 meta value.

In my example I'd like to pass in an array of values and find an exact match. Below is what I have so far, which can find the correct post ID but isn't an exact match. It returns the post ID if **any** of the values match in the array below. I need it to match **all** of the values.

```
// these values are dynamic, so multiple meta_query arrays are not an option
$array_of_values_to_match = array( '1', '2', '3' );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_some_meta_key', // they all have the same meta_key
            'value' => $array_of_values_to_match,
            'compare' => 'IN' // can't use = when passing in an array
        ),
    ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

As per the codex, `Array support is limited to a compare value of 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'`

So if my wp_postmeta table looked like the following, it should match list the post with the id of `122`

```
post_id   meta_key          meta_value
122       _some_meta_key    1
122       _some_meta_key    2
122       _some_meta_key    3
```

But **not** if it looked like this (there's no 3)

```
post_id   meta_key          meta_value
122       _some_meta_key    1
122       _some_meta_key    2
122       _some_meta_key    8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match them all, you have to add `'relation' => 'AND'` and check for each value separately:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_some_meta_key',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_some_meta_key',
            'value' => 2,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_some_meta_key',
            'value' => 3,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
);
```

To get around hardcoding this into the query, you can build your query args dynamically to add the relation and values based on the contents of your array:

```
$array_of_values_to_match = array( '1', '2', '3' );

// set some initial args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(),
);

// if there's more than 1 value, add the relation arg
if( 1 < count( $array_of_values_to_match ) ){
    $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
}

// for each of the array values, add a meta query for that value
foreach( $array_of_values_to_match as $val ){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => '_some_meta_key',
        'value' => $val,
        'compare' => '='
    );
}

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Ahh thanks Milo, so simple. Will give it a shot and report back.